# Knockout fallback view

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs, durandal-2.0, knockout-mvc

**Durandal, RequireJS, KnockoutJS**

I have a generic and a client specific view in my project.

```
│   faq.html
│   welcome.html
│   shell.html
│
├───Client1
│     faq.html
│
├───Client2
│     faq.html
│     welcome.html
```

I want to show the client specific view if it exists or else show the default view.

Something like this.

```
<div>
   <div data-bind="compose: { view:'views/Client1/faq.html', fallbackView: 'view/faq.html' }"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're better off handling this in your view-model than in your view. Durandal lets you use an observable property for its compose binding so you can do something like this:

```
<div>
   <div data-bind="compose: { view: currentView }"></div>
</div>
```

...

```
viewModel = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.currentView = ko.observable();

    self.loadView = require(['text!views/Client1/faq.html', 'text!view/faq.html'], function(clientView, defaultView) {
        if(clientView) {
            self.currentView('views/Client1/faq.html');
        } else {
            self.currentView('view/faq.html');
        }
    });

}
```

Trying to load the view path twice seems a bit redundant of course but if you don't have any other way to know if the view exists or not then it might be your best bet.